# Open DataReader error with SqlConnection

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

In my project,i have one function to retrieve data from Sql2005 Server
like this,

```
SqlConnection sqlCnn = new SqlConnection("");
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("Select user_id from users");
SqlDataReader sqlReader = null;

sqlCnn.Open();
sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCnn;
sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

if (sqlReader.HasRows)
{
    while (sqlReader.Read())
    {
        if(user_id == 1)
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select mobile from tbl");
            sqlCmd2.Connection = sqlCnn;
            sqlCmd2.ExecuteReader();
        }
    }
}
```

I got the following error when sqlcmd2 is executed.

> There is already an open DataReader
>   associated with this Command  which
>   must be closed first.

I don't want to create a new sqlconnection at there. Is there any way to solve 
this problem?

Comment: what data structure would make you not be able to execute this in one go? what are you trying to return? what's the relationship between the users table and tbl? why are you checking for user_id == 1? The more you can achieve in one go, the less overhead.

Comment: it is just sample code,we have to check and calculate after executing first command and based on that result,we will execute another command. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open two readers per connection you need to enable MARS (multiple active result sets).
You can do this via connection string:

```
 Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

However, it is not recommended approach.
I'm sure you can retrieve the data you need with one query.

You need to explain what you need to retrieve, if you want and advice on a single query.
I assumed that the code you showed just a sample, not a real one, as it does not make much sense.

Look at 'Is MARS all good news, or is there any downside?' section [here.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlnativeclient/archive/2006/09/27/774290.aspx)

Comment: we can't retrieve all data with single query because of our data structure.That's why we have to use another command,is there any problem in using that MARS? thanks

Comment: You can read about disadvantages here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlnativeclient/archive/2006/09/27/774290.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The best way to solve this is to join the two tables together at the database.  That should give you at least an order of magnitude performance increase, especially if there's an index on the appropriate column(s).

Data structure doesn't enter into this; it's all in how you order the results and how you go about reading them. Done correctly, you *can* read that into any data structure imaginable.

But if that's not an option, make sure you're using at least Sql Server 2005 and add `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` to your connection string.

And while you're at it, your existing code is broken and can eventually lead to your database being unavailable because you are not guaranteed to close your connections in the case where an exception occurs.  To solve this, create your SqlConnection object inside a `using` block.

Answer (score 1):

If you must not create a second SQL connection, then you could enable [MARS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx) (Multiple Active Result Sets).

Why do you not want a second connection?

Answer (score 0):

In .net 4, u dont need check hasrows condition. Reader.Read() method returns true/false based on table contents. Just checked with empty table. Worked!!